# SQL - League with two tables - team and match

Tags: sql, sqlite

My Tables are:

```
match 
  id_match
  id_teamhome
  id_teamaway
  goalhome
  goalaway

team
  id_team
  name_team
```

I try to select :

- The name of team that scored more goals .
- The name of team receives more goals in these nets .
- The name of team that scored more goal away .
- the name of team that received more goal away .

.
I've Tried:

```
select id_team , 
       sum(goalaway)+sum(goalhome) 
  from team, 
       match 
 where id_team = id_teamaway 
   and id_teamaway ;
```

And:

```
SELECT name_team, 
       max(goalaway, goalhome) 
  from team, 
       match 
 group by name_team
```

I'm using SQL lite
Any help Please !!!

Comment: So, `I try to select` can you show it please? SO is not a free code service. Show some effort and we for sure will help.

Comment: i tried for example select  id_team , sum(goalaway)+sum(goalhome) from team , match where id_team = id_teamaway and id_teamaway ;

Comment: and to be honest it was an exam , and i think i got 0 .

Comment: SELECT name_team, max(goalaway, goalhome) from team, match group by name_team;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you @michal , I will work Harder 
   .  @Jorge Campos  , I did a great job i think :-) 
  USING Oracle PL/SQL :-)
**

```
-- team table creation 
Create table team(
    team_id NUMBER(3),
    team_name VARCHAR(30),
    Constraint pk_team_id Primary key (team_id)
); 
--auto increment by 1 sq_team_id.nextvalue  
Create sequence sq_team_id 
    MINVALUE 1 
    MAXVALUE 999
    START WITH 1 
    INCREMENT BY 1 ; 
-- Game table creation 
create table game (
    game_id NUMBER(4),
    game_home_team_id NUMBER(3),
    game_away_team_id NUMBER(3),
    game_home_goal NUMBER(2),
    game_away_goal NUMBER(2),
    constraint pk_game_id primary key (game_id),
    Constraint fk_game_team_home Foreign key (game_home_team_id) REFERENCES TEAM (TEAM_ID),
    Constraint fk_game_team_away Foreign key (game_away_team_id) REFERENCES TEAM (TEAM_ID)
);
--auto increment by 1 sq_game_id.nextvalue  
Create sequence sq_game_id 
    MINVALUE 1 
    MAXVALUE 9999
    START WITH 1 
    INCREMENT BY 1 ; 
-- Insert Value to table team 
INSERT INTO TEAM VALUES (SQ_TEAM_ID.NEXTVAL,'Etoile de SAHEL');
INSERT INTO TEAM VALUES (SQ_TEAM_ID.NEXTVAL,'ESperence de Tunis');
INSERT INTO TEAM VALUES (SQ_TEAM_ID.NEXTVAL,'Club African');
INSERT INTO TEAM VALUES (SQ_TEAM_ID.NEXTVAL,'CLub Sfaxien');
COMMIT;

--insert values to table GAME
INSERT INTO GAME VALUES (SQ_GAME_ID.NEXTVAL,1,2,3,0);
INSERT INTO GAME VALUES (SQ_GAME_ID.NEXTVAL,2,1,2,2);
INSERT INTO GAME VALUES (SQ_GAME_ID.NEXTVAL,2,3,0,1);
INSERT INTO GAME VALUES (SQ_GAME_ID.NEXTVAL,3,2,0,0);
INSERT INTO GAME VALUES (SQ_GAME_ID.NEXTVAL,1,3,2,0); 
INSERT INTO GAME VALUES (SQ_GAME_ID.NEXTVAL,3,1,0,1); 
commit;

SELECT * from TEAM ; 
SELECT * FROM GAME ; 

-- selective display of all game played 
SELECT a.GAME_ID,b.TEAM_NAME "Home",a.GAME_HOME_GOAL as "Score Home",a.GAME_AWAY_GOAL as "Score away",c.TEAM_NAME as "AWAY" FROM GAME a 
INNER JOIN TEAM b ON a.GAME_HOME_TEAM_ID = b.TEAM_ID 
INNER JOIN TEAM c ON a.GAME_AWAY_TEAM_ID = c.TEAM_ID 
Order by a.GAME_ID;  

--- VIEW For Scored Goal HOME BY TEAM .
CREATE VIEW V_GOAL_HOME_BY_TEAM AS
SELECT a.TEAM_NAME,sum(b.GAME_HOME_GOAL)AS SCORED_GOAL_HOME FROM TEAM a 
INNER JOIN GAME b on  a.TEAM_ID = b.GAME_HOME_TEAM_ID 
Group by a.TEAM_NAME ; 

-- Test from View V_GOAL_HOME_BY_TEAM
select * from V_GOAL_HOME_BY_TEAM ;

--- VIEW For Scored Goal AWAY BY TEAM .
CREATE VIEW V_GOAL_AWAY_BY_TEAM AS
SELECT c.TEAM_NAME,Sum(d.GAME_AWAY_GOAL) AS SCORED_GOAL_AWAY FROM TEAM c 
INNER JOIN GAME d on  c.TEAM_ID = d.GAME_AWAY_TEAM_ID
group by c.TEAM_NAME;

-- Test View V_GOAL_AWAY_BY_TEAM 
select * from V_GOAL_AWAY_BY_TEAM ;

-- Create a view from the two view each team total score away and home
CREATE VIEW V_Scored_Goal AS 
SELECT a.TEAM_NAME,b.SCORED_GOAL_HOME,c.SCORED_GOAL_AWAY FROM TEAM a 
INNER JOIN V_GOAL_HOME_BY_TEAM b ON a.TEAM_NAME = b.TEAM_NAME
INNER JOIN V_GOAL_AWAY_BY_TEAM c ON a.TEAM_NAME = c.TEAM_NAME ; 
-- test for view 
select * from V_SCORED_GOAL ;

-- total goal scored by team oredred 
select TEAM_NAME,SCORED_GOAL_HOME+SCORED_GOAL_AWAY as TOTAL_SCORED from V_SCORED_GOAL order by TOTAL_SCORED DESC ;

-- Select Wich Team does not play any match 
SELECT TEAM_NAME from TEAM 
WHERE TEAM_NAME NOT IN ( SELECT TEAM_NAME from V_GOAL_AWAY_BY_TEAM ) 
AND TEAM_NAME NOT IN ( SELECT TEAM_NAME from V_GOAL_AWAY_BY_TEAM )  ; 


-- Team that scored less at home 
select TEAM_NAME FROM V_GOAL_HOME_BY_TEAM
WHERE SCORED_GOAL_HOME IN (SELECT MIN(SCORED_GOAL_HOME) FROM V_GOAL_HOME_BY_TEAM ) ; 
-- team that scored more goal away 
select TEAM_NAME FROM V_GOAL_AWAY_BY_TEAM
WHERE SCORED_GOAL_AWAY IN (SELECT MAX(SCORED_GOAL_AWAY) FROM V_GOAL_AWAY_BY_TEAM ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to study harder ;)

I would start with scored goals. View is not crucial, you can use the union all as a subquery.

```
create view scored_goals as
select id_teamhome as id_team, goalhome as goals, 'H' as ha_id from match
union all
select id_teamaway as id_team, goalaway as goals, 'A' as ha_id from match;
```

Now you have a view of all goals in all matches and you can sum:

```
select id_team, sum(goals) as goals from scored_goals group by id_team order by goals desc;
```

Add a condition to count away goals only:

```
select id_team, sum(goals) as goals from scored_goals where ha_id = 'A' group by id_team order by goals desc;
```

To get only team id that scored max you can add *limit 1* to the queries.
To get the team name you need to join the result to the other table.

```
select s.id_team, t.name_team, sum(s.goals) as goals from scored_goals as s 
join teams as t where s.id_team = t.id_team group by id_team 
order by goals desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Thankx you so much ... I promise you that i will give more time to database courses next weeks .